# Conditionally rendering components, but code is bloated with booleans and states, is there more efficient way?

Tags: reactjs, conditional-rendering

I'm refactoring my code as it was bloated with multiple if else statements & states.

My issue is the use of states & conditionally rendering. I've only been using boolean states to determine what image(wrong,correct,higher,lower jpgs) my component takes in as a prop depending on if the condition returns true or not.

e.g:

```
obj1["int"] === obj2["int"] ? setIsRight(true)
: obj1["int"] < obj2["int"] ? setIsHigher(true)
: setIsHigher(false);


{isRight ? (<ChampionHint text="Class"img={right}/>) 
: isHigher ? (<ChampionHint text="Class"img={higher}/>) 
: (<ChampionHint text="Class"img={lower}/>)}
```

To unrender the component I guess I would have to set isHigher and isRight to undefined/null? ( Not sure if this is 100% correct, I just learned this when going through documentation and planning on trying this after I figure out my initial issue)

The code above works when I'm only comparing one key value pair between two objects, but when I'm comparing multiple (in my case 4 key value pairs), I would have to add new states for each new iteration of conditional rendering. That's where the problem occurs, i would create more states, isRight2, isHigher2... isRight3, isHigher3... And then the code looks really bloated with states.

Is creating new states with similar conditions & using the same images still the way to go or is there a more efficient way of doing this?

My code for reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-khayyam-8tt3jv?file=/src/Home.tsx

Home.tsx is my old code, and NewRefactoring.tsx is my attempt to clean it up

This is the expected result.
[image: This is the expected result.]

Comment: Because all of this state is just controlling one element, couldn't you squeeze all of these booleans into one value? Maybe a string or number? I would even suggest storing the images in an array and then having the state being the index of the images array.

Comment: @kelly there would be 4 elements total, one for each key value pair. Is there a way of reusing the state & element for the other 3 pairs that I don't know about? I like the idea of the images array, I didn't think of that.

Comment: Can we see the entire component (or at least the state and how they are used)?

Comment: @kelly Yes, I just added it into the codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-khayyam-8tt3jv?file=/src/ChampionHint.tsx

1 question, could i initially set the states i'm using (isRight and isHigher) to undefined, and then later define it conditionally (e.g true or false) , and then set all of the states to undefined when I want to unrender them?